# How to create a custom Attribute Inspector for mobile app using the ESRI JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, mobile, fields-attributes, dojo

I am making a mobile version of a JS web application I developed.  I'm noticing though that the `AttributeInspector` widget by default uses standard `dojo/form` controls.  This means that the form within the widget does not work correctly on a mobile browser.

Is there a way to change the `AttributeInspector` so that it uses the `dojox/mobile` controls?  Right now, I am simply providing the `LayerInfos` object to constructor without specifying the `FieldInfos` object.  I'd like to avoid that if I can because I'd like the app to be able to use different layers with different fields.

Here is how I create the `AttributeInspector`:

```js
var layerInfos = this.layers.map(function(layer) {
    return {
        featureLayer : layer.layerObject,
        showAttachments : true,
        isEditable : layer.layerObject.isEditable()
    };
});

this.attInspector = new AttributeInspector({
    layerInfos : layerInfos
}, this.inspectorDiv);
this.attInspector.startup();
```

Here is what it looks like on my Android phone:

[image: Android Snapshot]

As you can see, the fields get cut off.  Also, the dropdown lists do not appear as they should on a mobile device.

Is there anyway to do this without writing a lot of code to account for different field types and domains?